# send data back to home screen without "onPress" functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I have a react native app.
I am trying to send some data back to my Home screen.
In the Home screen, the user clicks a button that will navigate to the Details screen.

home.js

```
param = {
date: 2021-05-01,
id: 001
}

this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', params)
```

Detail.js

```
parameter = {
date: 2021-05-01,
id: 001
}

let data = JSON.stringify(this.props.route.params)

{
parameter === data ?
//send some string back to home screen : null
}
```

So if the entries match in the "Details" screen i want to send some string like "PASSED" back to Home screen.

When the user clicks "back" button or swipes back to the Home screen i want it to send some data to the Home screen.
How do i do this?

Comment: Are you using in your app any state management library, like redux? Because if you do, you could dispatch an action which will put in your global state a flag or some data and therefore if you're going back to home screen all you have to do is to check that data state

Comment: nope not using redux

Comment: I understand. Another solution would be to use the local storage for this. If the `parameter === data`, store a key in the local storage and in the Home screen you'd have to check if there is any value for that key in the local storage, if there is -> perform action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like dianaqqq suggested, applying state management library like redux is the way how this is usually solved. If you do not wish to use external library for it, you could apply react context: 
 https://blog.devgenius.io/react-native-state-management-with-context-api-61f63f5b099

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html